# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.base'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm trying to run `from sklearn import preprocessing`, but it raise an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-d27a4e3c0526>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import preprocessing

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse

  File "/Users/x/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 227, in <module>
    from .base import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.base'
```

How could I deal with it?

The version of `scipy` is `1.5.4`.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling or just upgrading scipy? For me, this import worked with multiple versions including `1.5.4`.

Comment: I use `pip3 uninstall scipy` and `pip3 install scipy`, it raises an error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.19.4.dist-info/METADATA'`

Comment: One solution I saw was maybe going into the directory and if there's a `METADATA.json` file, rename it to just `METADATA`. I also saw that possibly moving the folder out from site-packages and then trying to install numpy would help.

Comment: Under `/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.19.4.dist-info` with command `ls`, output: `REQUESTED`. So neither `METADATA.json` or `METADATA` exists.

Comment: I found I have multiple `numpy-*.dist-info`: `numpy, numpy-1.14.3.dist-info, numpy-1.18.0.dist-info, numpy-1.18.5.dist-info, numpy-1.19.4.dist-info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pip3 install --upgrade --user scipy` solved the problem for me.