# Joblib.load error: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, joblib

- **Python version:** 3.7 (I have to use this version)
- **OS:** Linux
- **Cloud Platform:** Azure
- **Resource:** Azure function with python
- **Goal:** Load a model created with skit-learn version 1.0.2 with the following dependencies installed:

> numpy: 1.17.3 joblib: 1.1.0 scipy: 1.7.3

I am using joblib to load a skit-learn model that I trained (By the way I created the model locally in my machine with python 3.9). However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/home/site/wwwroot/sortierung/__init__.py\", line 51, in main
prediction_file_path)
File \"/home/site/wwwroot/shared_code/custom_functions_prediction.py\", line 255, in predict
result.update(classify_mail(m,s,X, stop_words, model_folder_path))
File \"/home/site/wwwroot/shared_code/custom_functions_prediction.py\", line 105, in classify_mail
model = load(modelFilePath)
File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py\", line 587, in load
obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
File \"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py\", line 506, in _unpickle
obj = unpickler.load()
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py\", line 1088, in load
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py\", line 1385, in load_stack_global
self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py\", line 1426, in find_class
__import__(module, level=0)\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'
```

I checked in the scipy folder installed and I could not find this module. How could I solve this issue?. Tks in advance

Comment: Do these answer your question? [ImportError: No module named scipy.sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043789/importerror-no-module-named-scipy-sparse) and [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.base'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-scipy-sparse-base)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT tks for your help. No, I already checked it and the problem is not with the installation of scipy as far as I understood.

Comment: It could be due to Python version. Reference: [No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050592/i-cannot-load-random-forest-model-using-joblib-i-am-getting-a-scipy-error)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT tks again for your prompt answer. I checked also already and the restriction that I have is that I have to use Python 3.7 because the machine in Azure has that version. Do you know what else can be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'` error, try the following way:

This error occurred because you have created a model in **Python 3.9** but running it on **Python 3.7**.

You can try creating a model in **Python 3.7** or upgrade the Azure Python function app to a specific version of  **Python 3.9**.

To change the Python version to 3.9, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#changing-python-version):

- You can update the `linuxFxVersion` setting in the function app with the `az functionapp config` set command.

```
az functionapp config set --name <FUNCTION_APP> \
--resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> \
--linux-fx-version "python|3.9"
```

References: [No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050592/i-cannot-load-random-forest-model-using-joblib-i-am-getting-a-scipy-error) and [How to change python version of azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000572/how-to-change-python-version-of-azure-function)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT, tks a lot for your support. The error was, as you said, I created my model with a high version of python and when I want to open that model with a lower version of python, I got that error. I trained and load my model with python 3.7 and it works like a charm. Tks again

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the last answer.

I have used **python 3.7.10** and **scipy 1.8.1** to dump the dict with csr matrix in local windows environment. After that, load the file in linux environment by **python 3.8.10** and **scipy 1.7.1**.

self.word_multi_model_feature = pickle.load(f_dict_feature)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'

You should change the load python environment to be same as the dump enviroment.